# How to prevent dark mode from changing OneNote pen color on PDFs?

Tags: pdf, microsoft-onenote, dark-mode

In OneNote for Office 365, system-wide dark mode generally causes pen colors to change to their 'dark' counterparts, most notably black to white.

However, for annotations on embedded PDFs, this is problematic because the PDF background remains white, thus creating a situation of white text on white background whenever dark mode is enabled. Is there a way to resolve this issue?